Default macOS notification image
I'm making a project in rust that needs to send a notification. I'm using the notify_rust package for this task.
On rust compile the notification image was the macOS finder image but when I clicked on the compiled binary (directly from finder) a popup showed up asking me to select a default application. I randomly choose an app but I was wondering if anyone knows if I can still change this default somewhere.
Here is the example code and link to the library I am using.
Notification::new()
    .summary("Safari Crashed")
    .body("Just kidding, this is just the notify_rust example.")
    .show()?;

https://github.com/hoodie/notify-rust/tree/c253a82f53c24ad29d4aeecec84952e53a886d52
